# Can't get my 1-D array to pass to my function in C

Tags: c

Hello I am having trouble sending the values from my 1-D array to my function in order to be able to calculate their value. Whenever I run the code I am getting numbers in my table but they are not the ones I declared in my array. Also, I am not sure if I should use the pow function to square the integer values inside the array or if I should just write it out the longer way. 
P.s the function I am using to calculate the values is Y = x^2/2 - x ln x

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 10

void valueY(int valueX[], int size);
int main()
{
int integerValues[N] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50};

valueY(integerValues[N], 10);
printf("\n\n\n\t\tEnd of Program\n");

return 0;
}
void valueY(int valueX[], int size)

{

int integerValues[N];
int i, t;
double ln_integer;
double result;
FILE *functionResults;
functionResults = fopen("C:/Users/Desktop/FunctionY_results.txt", "w");

if ( functionResults == NULL )
{
    printf("\nERROR: File could not be opened for writing.\n");

}

fprintf(functionResults,"\n\n\tValue of x:\tValue of Y:,(y = (x^2/2) - x * ln(integer))\n");
printf("\n\n\tValue of x:\tValue of Y:,(y = (x^2/2) - x * ln(integer))\n");

ln_integer = log(integerValues[N]);
result = (pow(integerValues[N], 2)/2) - (integerValues[N] * ln_integer);

for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    printf("\n");
    fprintf(functionResults, "\n");
    for ( t = 0; t < 1; t++)
    {
        printf("\t%d", integerValues[i]);
        fprintf(functionResults, "\t%d", integerValues[i]);
        printf("\t\t%.2f\n", result);
        fprintf(functionResults,"\t\t%.2f\n", result);

    }
    result = 0;
}


fclose(functionResults);

}
```

Comment: valueY(integerValues[N], 10); should be valueY(integerValues, N). Aside from that you are using wrong indexing in valueY function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
valueY(integerValues[N], 10);
```

This is the call in your `main()`, which is the cause of the problem. When running, this line of code actually means:

```
valueY(integerValues[10], 10);
```

and `integerValues[10]` should have some garbage data (since you are declaring `integerValues` as an array with 10 elements, you should only access `integerValues[0]` to `integerValues[9]`, but not `integerValues[10]`).

What you want to do is either

```
valueY(&integerValues[0], 10);
```

or

```
valueY(integerValues, 10);
```

which are basically the same thing.

**edit:**
As Omid has pointed out, it is better to write

```
valueY(integerValues,N);
```

as `N` is defined to be the size of the array, so the code can be generic.

Comment: You mean pass N instead of 10 so it works generically.

Comment: @omid sorry I can not understand which line of code you are commenting on. Can you explain further?

Comment: valueY(integerValues, 10); should be valueY(integerValues, N); so it can be generic